# Restrict selecting date older than today in CakePHP Input Form

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I am using CakePHP 3.8 to show date input boxes on UI. But it should not take a date which is older than today's date.  Like in jQuery datepicker we set minDate to restrict selecting previous dates.

Same I want to do with CakePHP inbuild input box to restrict the previous date selection.

```
echo $this->Form->input('expiry_date', [
    'type' => 'date',
    'required',
    'default' => date('Y-m-d') // Show default Todays date
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass normal HTML attributes in the options too, like `min` for date inputs:

```
echo $this->Form->input('expiry_date', [
    'type' => 'date',
    'required',
    'default' => date('Y-m-d'), // Show default Todays date,
    'min' => date('Y-m-d')
]);
```

This will mark the field invalid if an older date is entered.